# Click in a vector plot to plot several solutions of a system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, dynamic

I am aware of the Locator button and I am aware of the Equation Trekker package, but they are not what I want to use. Here is what I specifically want to know how to do, if possible. Consider the system:

\begin{align*}
x'&=2x+3y\\
y'&=3x+2y
\end{align*}

Create a vector plot.

```
A = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}};
F[x_, y_] = A.{x, y};
VectorPlot[F[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None},
 VectorPoints -> 16]
```

[image]

Now my question. What I want to be able to do is use my mouse to click a point in the vector plot and as a result, the solution trajectory will be added to the vector plot. I also want to be able to do this repeatedly, click the mouse several times and then several trajectory solutions are plotted on the vector plot starting at the clicked point initial condition.

Is this possible using Mathematica?

**KGLR Suggestion:** OK, gave your idea Epilog -> {vp[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALXW9m.png)], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[u]} a try:

```
ClearAll[a, vp, x, y]
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}};
vp = VectorPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, VectorPoints -> 16];
options = {PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[u]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp]};
```

Then:

```
Manipulate[
 z = NDSolveValue[
     Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], x[0], y[0]} == Join[a.{x@t, y@t}, #]], {x@
       t, y@t}, {t, -2, 1}] & /@ u;
 ParametricPlot[z, {t, -2, 1}, Evaluate@options], {{u, {}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, {z, {}, None}, 
 Paneled -> False]
```

But I got the following image result and the warning message: "Coordinate $CellContext`u should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

[image]

However, I still tried the PasteSnapshot and got an image with the dots, but for some reason I can't include it in this post.

So, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Using the options directly inside `ParametricPlot`, i.e., `Manipulate[
 z = NDSolveValue[ Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], x[0], y[0]} == Join[a.{x@t, y@t}, #]], {x@ t, y@t}, {t, -2, 1}] & /@ u;
 ParametricPlot[z, {t, -2, 1}, Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[u]},   PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True,   PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp]], {{u, {}}, Locator, Appearance -> None,  LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, {z, {}, None}, Paneled -> False]`  prevents the error....

Comment: ... or, change `Point[u]` to `Point[pnts]` inside `options` and change `Evaluate@options` to `Evaluate@(options /. pnts -> u)` inside `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: I think the first approach is cleaner/safer so that you all symbols are inside `Manipulate`. You can also `Initialization` to define `options`, i.e, add `Initialization :> {options = {Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red,  PointSize[Large], Point[u]}, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1,   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True,  PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp]}}`.

Comment: @kguler: Wow! And you can drag the dot as if it were a locator button, adjusting the trajectory curves.Then when you Paste Snapshot at the end, the red dots still appear. I've found that Ctrl+Clicking the snapshot and saving as a .eps file (.pdf is still a bug when you do this) can be well used in a LaTeX document. I really appreciate your effort on my behalf. My students will benefit from your kindness.

Comment: really glad to know it is useful for you and your students.

Comment: @kguler: Look what I was able to do because of your help. See [here](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/spring2015/sections/section8_3.nb)

Answer (score 16):

**Update 2:** Using `DynamicSetting` to turn `Manipulate` into an input expression to print snapshots:

```
ClearAll[x, y, u, z, a, t, plot, manipulate]

manipulate = Manipulate[Module[{a = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}}, vp}, 
    vp = VectorPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
      VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, VectorPoints -> 16];
    z = NDSolveValue[Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], x[0], y[0]} == 
          Join[a.{x@t, y@t}, #]], {x@t, y@t}, {t, -2, 1}] & /@ u;
    plot = ParametricPlot[z, {t, -2, 1}, ImageSize -> 200, 
      Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[u]}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp]]], {{u, {}}, Locator, 
    Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, {z, {}, None}, {plot, {}, None}];
```

Evaluate the following line in place, i.e. highlight it and use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`:

```
DynamicSetting[manipulate]
```

To print the current snapshot in the next cell use `Shift+Enter`:
[image]

---

**Update:** Adding a button to print a snapshot:

```
Manipulate[Module[{a = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}}, vp}, 
  vp = VectorPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, VectorPoints -> 16]; 
  z = NDSolveValue[Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], x[0], y[0]} == Join[a.{x@t, y@t}, #]], 
    {x@t, y@t}, {t, -2, 1}] & /@ u;
  plot = ParametricPlot[z, {t, -2, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[u]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp]]],
 {{u, {}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, 
 {z, {}, None}, {plot, {}, None}, 
 Button["Print snapshot in next cell", SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell];
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], ToBoxes@plot]]]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

You *can* use `Locator` with the option setting [`LocatorAutoCreate->All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorAutoCreate.html) to

> create a new locator with any mouse click

```
ClearAll[a, vp, x, y]
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}};
vp = VectorPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
     VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, VectorPoints -> 16];
dot = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
options = {PlotStyle -> Red, Epilog -> vp[[1]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp]};
```

Using the functions returned by `NDSolveValue` as the first argument of  `ParametricPlot` and using `vp` above as `Epilog`, we can let `Manipulate` manage the mouse click events:

```
Manipulate[z = NDSolveValue[Thread[{x'[t], y'[t], x[0], y[0]}==Join[a.{x@t, y@t}, #]], 
                           {x@t, y@t}, {t, 0, 1}] & /@ u;
 ParametricPlot[z, {t, 0, 1}, Evaluate@options], 
 {{u, {}}, Locator,  Appearance -> dot, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, 
 {z, {}, None},  AppearanceElements -> {}, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** With option setting `LocatorAutoCreate->All`, you can remove any existing locator using `Alt+Click`.

Comment: Two outstanding presentations! I have two questions on this one. First, when I delete ImageSize->20, it no longer works properly. Very strange. How come? Second, how can a student export the final image to a pdf file. Ctrl+click does not work.

Comment: @David, re `ImageSize->20` puzzling indeed -- don't know why removing `ImageSize`  affects how `LocatorAutoCreate`  behaves. Re exporting the final image, you can use ` // Setting` to the right of  the manipulate object and Evaluate the cell to create a graphics object with the current settings which then can be saved as pdf using   `Save Selection As ...`  Better way would be to add an export button inside  Manipulate. If you remove `AppearanceElements-{}` from the code, you can also use `Paste Snapshot` and evaluate the resulting cell to get a static graphics that can exported as usual.

Comment: ...  Re locator appearance: you can also use `Appearance->None` and  add the red dots into the `Epilog` settings: `Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[u]}` .

Comment: I tried the //Setting to the right of the manipulate object, but then clicking in the vector field did not work. I tried removing the AppearanceElements->{}, then clicked on the little + button in the upper right hand corner, selected Paste Snapshot and a huge amount of code was produced (any way to suppress that?), which when compiled, produced my image, which I was then able to save. The dots disappeared, so no I understand your last comment and will give it a try. Thanks for this awesome work.

Comment: Interesting. If you remove AppearanceElements-{} and Paneled->False in your original code, then do a Paste Snapshot, the locators disappears and the panel disappears, leaving a very good image for the students to save.

Answer (score 8):

Using the "almost new" feature of `NDSolve[]` that allows it to detect vector equations based upon the dimensions of the initial conditions.

```
a = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}};
vp = VectorPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Axes -> True, 
                AxesLabel -> {x, y}, VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None}, 
                VectorPoints -> 16];


DynamicModule[{pt, ss = {{pt -> ({5, 5} &)}}},
 EventHandler[ Dynamic@ Show[vp, ParametricPlot[pt@t/. ss, {t,0,1}, PlotStyle->Red],
                             Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pt@0 /. ss]}],
               "MouseDown" :> AppendTo[ss, First@NDSolve[{pt'@t == a.pt@t, 
                              pt@0 == MousePosition["Graphics"]}, pt, {t, 0, 1}]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Or using some tweaks in @kguler's answer you may also do:

```
DynamicModule[{pt, ss = {}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic@ParametricPlot[Through@ss@t, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Epilog -> 
     {vp[[1]], PointSize[Large], Red, Point@Through@ss@0}, PlotRange -> PlotRange@vp],
  "MouseDown" :> 
  AppendTo[ss, NDSolveValue[{pt'@t == a.pt@t, pt@0 == MousePosition["Graphics"]},
      pt, {t, 0, 1}]]]]
```

Comment: For some reason, this second version makes the Frame disappear.