# Clicking phase plane with mouse

Tags: differential-equations

Here is what I have thus far:

```
SetOptions[VectorPlot,
  VectorScale -> {0.045, .9, None},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  VectorPoints -> 16,
  VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}];
SetOptions[ContourPlot,
  ContourStyle -> {Orange, Green}];
SetOptions[ParametricPlot,
  PlotStyle -> Blue];
```

I made the above an initialization cell. Next, I have this:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{f, g, tmin, tmax, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
  tmin = -2; tmax = 2;
  xmin = -2; xmax = 4;
  ymin = -4; ymax = 2;
  f[x_, y_] = 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y;
  g[x_, y_] = x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y;
  ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
  z = NDSolveValue[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == {f[x[t], y[t]], 
         g[x[t], y[t]]}, {x[0], y[0]} == #}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, 
       tmax}] & /@ u;
  Show[
   VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}],
   ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, 
     ymin, ymax}],
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. ptRules}],
   ParametricPlot[z, {t, tmin, tmax}]]],
 {{u, {}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All},
 {z, {}, None}, Paneled -> False]
```

Running the manipulate gives this image.

[image]

Now use your mouse to click anywhere in the phase plane vector field and a solution trajectory will be drawn.

Now my question. Each time I click in the vector field, it shrinks, then expands, then draws. Can anything be done to stop this motion (shrink, expand on each click)?

Second question: The cell indicators on the right margin are blinking. What's up with that?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you seen `EquationTrekker`?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77299/click-in-a-vector-plot-to-plot-several-solutions-of-a-system-of-differential-equ

Answer (score 7):

**Updated:**

added `PlotTheme -> None` so it does not blink when resizing the window. 
[reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73489/resizing-or-moving-notebook-window-causes-manipulate-to-update-its-argument)

**Original**

This works for me, no blinking and no change in size. Added `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` for the vector plot.

```
 Manipulate[Module[{f, g, tmin, tmax, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax}, 
  tmin = -2; tmax = 2;
  xmin = -2; xmax = 4;
  ymin = -4; ymax = 2;
  f[x_, y_] = 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y;
  g[x_, y_] = x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y;
  ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
  z = NDSolveValue[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == {f[x[t], y[t]], g[x[t], y[t]]}, 
      {x[0], y[0]} == #}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}] & /@ u;
  Show[VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotTheme -> None], 
   ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotTheme -> None],
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. ptRules}], 
   ParametricPlot[z, {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotTheme -> None]]
  ], 
  {{u, {}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, 
   {z, {}, None}, Paneled -> False, 
 Initialization :> 
  {SetOptions[VectorPlot, VectorScale -> {0.045, .9, None}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, VectorPoints -> 16, 
    VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}];
   SetOptions[ContourPlot, ContourStyle -> {Orange, Green}];
   SetOptions[ParametricPlot, PlotStyle -> Blue]}]
```

ps. I put the plot options in the manipulate. But it should work if you remove them outside.

Comment: Cool! Can something similar be done to keep the nullclines from crinkling and something to get the parametric plot to motion with more quality?

Comment: @David, isn't that the trade-off of quality for speed?

Comment: @Nasser Excellent contributions! We are still experiencing blinking cell brackets when portions of both outputs are visible in one window. Any thoughts? Secondly, where do you think the Quiet command should be applied so that NDSolveValue doesn't report things?

Comment: @Michael E2 Could you also take a look at this project and help us answer the question about the blinking cell brackets?

Comment: @kguler Could you also take a look at our blinking cell bracket problem?

Comment: @David I do not see any blinking cell problem?  If you mean the cell side become black when you click on the Manipulate, then that is expected ofcourse as Manipulate is updating (busy). If you mean when you readjust the notebook size, then added PlotTheme->None fixes this. I updated.

Comment: @Nasser Still blinking. I recorded a video. You can watch it [here](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/spring2015/ExplanatoryActivities/PhasePlanePortraitsManipulate2/). You can also download the file [here](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/spring2015/ExplanatoryActivities/PhasePlanePortraitsManipulate2.nb). Maybe some of the stuff on [this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49257/problems-with-manipulate-indicated-by-blinking-output-cell) might help. But you need to look at a file with two manipulate outputs.

Comment: Adding TrackedSymbols :> {u} just stopped the blinking, but I think there is still a lot for me to learn based on the [reading here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49257/problems-with-manipulate-indicated-by-blinking-output-cell)

Comment: @David this is strange. On my system (windows 7, V 10.02) I do not see any blinking.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take with a view toward optimizing update/response time:

```
With[
 (* constants that won't change *)
 {vpopts = {VectorScale -> {0.045, .9, None}, Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {x, y}, VectorPoints -> 16, 
    VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]}},
  cpopts = {ContourStyle -> {Orange, Green}},
  ppopts = {PlotStyle -> Blue},
  tmin = -2, tmax = 2,
  xmin = -2, xmax = 4,
  ymin = -4, ymax = 2},
 Manipulate[
  (* parameters that might be changed by adding controls *)
  f = Function[{x, y}, 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y];
  g = Function[{x, y}, x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y];
  ptRules = NSolve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]; 
  With[{background = Show[
    VectorPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, vpopts],
    ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, cpopts],
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. ptRules}]
    ]},
   (* stuff that needs updating every click/drag *)
   Dynamic@Show[
     background,
     ParametricPlot[Evaluate[z /@ u], {t, tmin, tmax}, ppopts]
     ]
   ],
  {{u, {}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All},
  {{z, z}, None}, {f, None}, {g, None}, {ptRules, None},
  Initialization :>
   (* stores (memoizes) solution after click *)
   (z[pt_] := If[$ControlActiveSetting, #, z[pt] = #] &@
     NDSolveValue[
      {{x'[t], y'[t]} == {f[x[t], y[t]], g[x[t], y[t]]}, {x[0], y[0]} == pt},
      {x[t], y[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}]),
  Paneled -> False]
 ]
```

When I write a dynamic class example like this one, I think of symbols as falling into three categories: Some "variables" may really be constants; some may be parameters that are updated only to change the nature of the example; some are meant to be varied frequently to explore the example.  Here I've somewhat arbitrarily divided according to what categories they could fall into, in order to illustrate the principle.  If `f` and `g` are not to change, they can be moved into the `With` outside of `Manipulate`; and the `With` with the `background` could be nested between the outermost `With` and the `Manipulate`.

The `Dynamic` wrapping the `Show` means that only the `Show` is updated when the locators `u` change.

The solutions are cached in `z` when the mouse is released.  It's unlikely that a user will re-click on a locator, since they're invisible.  This means that the solutions will not be recalculated as new ones are added.  Note that the declaration `{{z, z}, None}` means that `z` will be initialized to itself; in other words, it won't be set equal to `0`, which occurs by default and which would break the `SetDelayed` definition in the `Initialization` option.  Or in other-other words, it's an uninitialization initialization. :)

Comment: Amazing response. I am going to learn a lot, thanks to your help, and my students will benefit.

Comment: One comment you made in the code was (* parameters that might be changed by adding controls *). Can you share an example of you might change these functions by adding a control?

Comment: Never mind. Just discovered your response at [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78146/entering-an-differential-equation-in-a-manipulate-box](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78146/entering-an-differential-equation-in-a-manipulate-box).

Comment: @David, Another way is to have an `InputField` with the declaration `{{vf, {2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y, x - 3 y - 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 3 x y}}, InputField}`, and define `{f, g} = Function @@ {{x, y}, #} & /@ vf` in the body of the `Manipulate`.  One could also have an input field `{{$f, 2 x - y + 3 (x^2 - y^2) + 2 x y, "f"}, InputField}` for each function and define `f = Function @@ {{x, y}, $f}`.