# Entering an differential equation in a Manipulate box

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

Does anyone have an example of a Manipulate demonstration where the user can type into a box the differential equation, time interval, initial condition, and the result is plotted?

This possible in Mathmatica?

Comment: It's certainly possible.  But if all those things are going into one box, it has to be in a valid code form (or at least it's much simpler that way).  E.g. enter `NDSolve[<stuff>]` or enter it between list braces `{de, ic, time}`.  You would have to construct the `NDSolve` code from it.  Is that the sort of thing you're after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach.  With a little `Rule`/`ReplaceAll` manipulation, it can accommodate some 
typical errors due to inattention to details of syntax.  These can be removed if it is a goal to get students to enter proper *Mathematica* syntax.

Adapting [some code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information/20370#20370)
from
[rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer), we can catch ] messages and display them inside the `Manipulate` if the user types incorrect input.  One may want to filter which messages are caught, as some are only warnings; see [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Check.html) for details.

```
SetAttributes[catchMessages, HoldAll];
catchMessages[code_] := Module[{myMessageList = {}},
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message, $InMsg = False},
   Unprotect[Message];
   Message[msg_, vars___] /; ! $InMsg := 
    Block[{$InMsg = True}, 
     AppendTo[myMessageList, StringForm[msg, vars]];
     Message[msg, vars]];
   (*code to run*)
   Check[code, Join[{$Failed}, myMessageList]]]]

Manipulate[
 update;
 With[{dep = First[Cases[ode, Derivative[_][var_] :> var, Infinity, Heads -> True]]},
  With[{indep = First[Cases[ode, Derivative[_][dep][x_] | dep[x_] :> x, Infinity] /.
    {} -> {x}]},
   With[{sol = Quiet@catchMessages[
        First@NDSolve[{ode, ics} /. {v : Derivative[_][_][_] :> v, 
            w : Derivative[_][_] :> w[indep], u : dep[_] :> u, 
            dep -> dep[indep]}, dep, Flatten[{indep, interval}]]]},
    If[FreeQ[sol, $Failed],
     Plot[Evaluate[dep[indep] /. sol], Evaluate@Flatten[{indep, dep["Domain"] /. sol}]],
     Column[
      Join[sol,
       {ode} /. {v : Derivative[_][_][_] :> v, w : Derivative[_][_] :> w[indep],
         u : dep[_] :> u, dep -> dep[indep]}]]]
    ]]],
 {{ode, y'' + y == 0}, InputField},
 {{ics, {y'[0] == 3., y[0] == 1.}}, InputField},
 {{interval, {0, 1}}, InputField},
 {{update, 0}, None}, Button["update", update++],
 TrackedSymbols :> {update}
 ]
```

The default independent variable is `x`. If a dependent variable appears with an argument, it is taken as the independent variable.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Correcting homework and quizzes right now, but rest assured I will give this a serious study this week. Great answer!