# Why doesn't this expression evaluate inside Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Consider this simplified code:

```
Manipulate[Ceiling[c - w/2], {c, Floor[w/2], 200}, {w, 1, 2, 1}]
```

It gives me a manipulator, in which I see the following content:

```
Ceiling[-(1/2) + 0]
```

But when I copy-paste it into a cell, I get this (after transforming to `InputForm`):

```
Ceiling[-1/2 + Dynamic[Floor[w$$/2], ImageSizeCache -> {87.8, {19.3, 28.66}}]]
```

Apparently, `w$$` is a custom-generated name for `w` by `Manipulate`. But why isn't it actually evaluated for display? And how do I force final result to appear in the window?

Comment: You can specify an initial value, this forces immediate evaluation: `Manipulate[
 Ceiling[c - w/2], {{c, 1, "c"}, Floor[w/2], 200}, {w, 1, 2, 1}]`

Comment: @Feyre yes I'm aware of it, but I'd like to know what happens in the case I presented. Also, if I supply the default value, it should be the left border of the range, and I can't do it with expression depending on `w` for the same reason as why this doesn't work.

Comment: Feyre shows the correct way to fix this - just assign a starting value. The Manipulate assigns a temporary variable that needs to be set in order to evaluate the expression. So the answer to your question is: to force the final result to appear in the window, you need to initialize w. This is done exactly as Feyre shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html)
and [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) (and their introductory siblings) have been read.  In particular the notions that `Manipulate` creates a `DynamicModule`, which is an inert piece of code that comes to life only when it is displayed by the Front End; and further, every time it is displayed by the Front End, a new instance is created, with new localized variables etc.

In

```
Manipulate[Ceiling[c - w/2], {c, Floor[w/2], 200}, {w, 1, 2, 1}]
```

the variable declaration

```
{c, Floor[w/2], 200}
```

initializes `c` to the expression `Floor[w/2]` with an uninitialized `DynamicModule` variable represented by `w` in the code, but in keeping with such variables, it is coded as the symbol `w$$`. inside the code `Manipulate` generates.  Since `w` is a `Manipulate` variable, `Manipulate` adds a `Dynamic` wrapper to it.  It does this automatically (and perhaps undocumentedly), and it usually is just what the user wanted (but didn't know was necessary).

The symbol `w$$` is instantiated when the FE creates an instance of the `DynamicModule` (that is created by `Manipulate`), and the name is changed to a localized symbol such as `` FE`w$$1379 `` in the `` FE` `` context and with a module number appended.

When the expression `Ceiling[c - w/2]` is displayed inside a `Dynamic` in the front end, the current values of the localized `w` and `c` are shown.  They are not subtracted because until you move the slider, `c` is the expression `Dynamic[Floor[w/2]]` and not a number.  When you copy the expression from the displayed `Manipulate`, you usually get the values as displayed inside the `Dynamic[]` that wraps the body of the `Manipulate`.  In this case though, what is inside the `Ceiling[]` is `Dynamic[Floor[w/2]] - w/2` and `Dynamic` is `HoldAll`.  So what *Mathematica* decides to copy, is the value of the second `w/2` but the whole `Dynamic[]` expression for the first term. The `Dynamic[]` code is copied as `Dynamic[w$$/2]`, which is the `InputForm` and not the temporary, active, Front-End form.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132644/4999