# How to change Label in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I would like to have the [`Label`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Label.html) called beta being shown with the Greek letter, without renaming the variable beta. This is my try so far, which is not what I want because Greek beta (β) is not substituting beta.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[beta x , {x, 0, 1}], 
 {{beta, "β="}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: `{beta, 0, "\[Beta]="}`

Comment: @garej i'm sorry could you write the whole code?

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[beta x , {x, 0, 1}], 
 {{beta, 0, "β="}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`. You've missed a starting value of beta between beta and its alias.

Comment: Related: [(132548)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132548/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[beta x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
 , {{beta, 0, "β="}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]