# How can I draw phase portrait of a matrix with given several initial points?

Tags: plotting, matrix, linear-algebra, difference-equations, homework

```
m1 = {{1, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.8}}
m2 = {{0.5, 0.9}, {0.7, 0.7}}
m3 = {{1.0, 0.2}, {-0.2, 1.0}}
m4 = {{-0.5, 1.0}, {0.5, 0.8}}

pt1 = {1, 1};
pt2 = {1, 0.5};
pt3 = {1.3, 0.7};
pt4 = {0.7, 1.3};
```

I have tried `ParametricPlot`, `DiscretePlot`, `StreamPlot`, `VectorPlot` and thought that `VectorPlot` would fit, but I guess there's a better way.
'Cause `VectorPlot` shows the vectors, not the real-line trajectories.
I mean for each matrix, the trajectories will show how the points will go.
So there should be 4 pictures separately.

Please help!

Comment: Could you clarify what the phase portrait of a matrix is?

Comment: I mean the phase portrait as a picturized set of trajectories, each made by a particular initial point.

Comment: Still not quite sure what you mean... something along [these lines](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EigenvaluesAndLinearPhasePortraits/)?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Do you think the picture that I added will work?

Comment: What textbook are you using that has you drawing things like these?

Comment: @J.M. It's 'DiscreteTime Models' from "A course in mathematical biology" that my Linear Algebra Professor provided us.

Answer (score 4):

With my [phase portrait package](https://github.com/cekdahl/PhasePortrait) it would be done like this:

```
<< PhasePortrait`

Show[
 VectorPlot[m2.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}],
 PhasePortrait[
  Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == m2.{x[t], y[t]}],
  {x, y}, t, {{-4, -4}, {4, 4}},
  GenerateInitialValues -> False,
  InitialValues -> {pt2},
  PlotStyle -> Green
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have several sets of trajectories and you want to plot them together.

Let's assume your trajectories are `trj[1],...`. You can use `Arrow` to plot them with `Graphics`.

```
Table[trj[n] = Table[t {Cos[2 Pi t + n], Sin[2 Pi t + n]}, {t, 0.2, 1.2, 0.05}]
                    , {n, 5}];

Graphics[{Arrowheads[{0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}], Table[Arrow[trj[n]], {n, 5}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I am not sure if this is what you want. If you can provide more details, I can modify my answer.

for your case, you can try

```
pts = {pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4};
ms = {m1, m2, m3, m4};

Do[{A[1], B[1]} = pts[[i]];
   trj[i] = Table[{A[n + 1], B[n + 1]} = ms[[i]].{A[n], B[n]}, {n, 100}], {i, 4}]

Graphics[{Arrowheads[{0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05}], Table[Arrow[trj[i]], {i, 4}]}, 
          Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}]
```

Comment: The picture looks like it is what I want to mimic.... Thanks. Though, all I need is one variable 'n'. For example, {A(n+1), B(n+1)}=m1.{A(n), B(n)} where {A(1),B(1)}={1,1} (something like this). With this information, what I want to demonstrate is one axis with A(n) and the other with B(n) just like cosine and sine on your instance.

Comment: Your answer really helped me much

Answer (score 3):

See also: [Related Q/A - 77299](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77299/125)

You can try the option `StreamPoints` with `VectorPlot`:

```
VectorPlot[m2.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{pt2, Directive[Thick, Green]}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

For all four pairs of matrices and points:

```
data = Transpose[{{m1, m2, m3, m4}, {pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4}, {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}}];

Row[VectorPlot[#.{x, y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
    StreamPoints -> {{{#2, Directive[Thick, #3]}}, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 250] & @@@ data]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Aliicia, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.