# Boundary condition change in coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

[MSE ode coupled question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834195/solve-parametric-differential-equation-using-mathematica)

What is a better way to code using *Mathematica* in my answer in order to visualize a dynamic situation between given $(x,y)$ field limits for several starting curves/points?

I shall link your replies there.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** You can control (move / remove / add) initial values dynamically using `Locator`s  as in, for example, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77308/125).

```
tm = 15;
EQ1[a_, b_] := {X'[t] == X[t] (1 - Y[t]),  Y'[t] == 1 + Y[t] (X[t] - 1), 
   X[0] == a, Y[0] == b};
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[EQ1[a, b], {X, Y}, {t, 0, tm}, {a, b}];

ab = {{- 0.4, 2.75}, {-.2, 4}, {4.4, 3.75}};

manipulate = Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[Through@pf[a[[1]], a[[2]]][t], {a, u}]], {t, 0, tm}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All,
     BaseStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, 
     Epilog -> ListPlot[{Labeled[#, Style[#, 16, "Panel"]]} & /@ u, 
        PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]][[1]]],
   {{u, ab}, Locator, Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}];
```

Evaluate the following line in place, i.e. highlight it and use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

```
DynamicSetting[manipulate]
```

[image]

To print the current snapshot in the next cell use `Shift+Enter`:

[image]

**Original answer:**

You might find [ParametricNDSolveValue](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) convenient:

```
tm = 10;
EQ1[a_, b_] := {X'[t] == X[t] (1 - Y[t]),  Y'[t] == 1 + Y[t] (X[t] - 1), 
  X[0] == a, Y[0] == b};
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[EQ1[a, b], {X, Y}, {t, 0, tm}, {a, b}];

ab = {{- 0.4, 2.75}, {-.2, 4}, {4.4, 3.75}};

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[Through @ pf[a[[1]], a[[2]]][t], {a, ab}]], {t, 0, tm}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> Thick,
 Epilog -> ListPlot[Labeled[#, Style[#, 16, "Panel"]] & /@ ab, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]][[1]]]
```

[image]

```
colors = Partition[ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; 6]], 2];
Table[cf[ab[[i]]] = colors[[i]], {i, Length@ab}];

Show[Table[Plot[Evaluate[Through@pf[a[[1]], a[[2]]][t]], {t, 0, tm},
  BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> cf[a], 
  PlotLegends -> (TraditionalForm /@ ({X[##][t], Y[##][t]} & @@ a))], {a, ab}]]
```

[image]