# Speeding up a dynamic vector plot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, dynamic

I would like to create a vector plot with a solution such that the vector plot is based on an underlying parameter en that I can adjust. With the help of [Click in a vector plot to plot several solutions of a system of differential equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77299/click-in-a-vector-plot-to-plot-several-solutions-of-a-system-of-differential-equ), I was able to do this in the following way:

```
ClearAll[x, y, u, z, a, t, plot, manipulate]
V[x_] := (-5)*Exp[-x^2]
manipulate = 
  Manipulate[
   Module[{vp}, 
    vp = VectorPlot[{1, (Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(V[x] - en + 1) - 
        1}, {x, -3, 3}, {\[Theta], -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, VectorPoints -> 40, 
      Ticks -> {Automatic, {-3 Pi/2, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}}];
    
    z = NDSolveValue[
        Thread[{x'[t], \[Theta]'[t], x[0], \[Theta][0]} == 
          Join[{1, (Cos[\[Theta]@t])^2*(V[x@t] - en + 1) - 
             1}, #]], {x@t, \[Theta]@t}, {t, -6, 6}] & /@ u;
    
    plot = 
     ParametricPlot[z, {t, -6, 6}, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Epilog -> {vp[[1]], Red, PointSize[Small], Point[u]}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Theta]"}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> PlotRange[vp], 
      GridLines -> {None, Table[(2 n + 1) Pi/2, {n, -6, 6}]}, 
      GridLinesStyle -> {Thick, Green}, 
      Ticks -> {Automatic, {-3 Pi/2, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 
         3 Pi/2}}]], {{u, {}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, 
    LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, {en, -5, 0}, {z, {}, None}, {plot, {}, 
    None}];
DynamicSetting[manipulate]
```

But I ran into a speed problem. In particular, it takes a few seconds to load each frame, so it is impossible to continuously vary en. I would like to do this to show how the solution moves as a change en.

On a related but separate note, I want the solution $\theta(x)$ that I will show to satisfy $\theta \left(-3\right)=\arccos \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-E}}.$ The problem is that this condition is dependent on en, but my current code fixes the initial conditions upon a mouse click. I just want to plot this particular solution and show how it varies as I continuously change en. How can I do this? (I am new to Mathematica, so hopefully this question is not too basic!) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a tip: You might get more people to tackle a somewhat complicated-looking problem if you provided complete, working code. For I know, `V[x]` could be a factor.

Comment: Provide definition for `V[x]`.  Also, are you certain you need `DynamicSetting`?  Are you using your plot as input for another function?

Comment: Thank you Michael, I added that. Edmund, I am not using my plot as an input. In light of that, perhaps you can share the better code which does not use DynamicSetting? Thanks!